# bf cache in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the back/forward-button on my mobile site. First I have to mention, that I want to show a loading-page-gif with that code if pageload needs more than a half second:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function(e,data){


   setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$('#loading_image').hasClass('schnell')) {
      $('#loading_image').addClass('loading_image');
      $(window).load(function(){
        $('#loading_image').fadeOut(1500);
      });
  }
 }, 500);

});

$(window).load(function(){
   $('#loading_image').addClass('schnell');
});
```

This works fine but not on one special site with google maps (with an iframe) **when the user goes to the page by the back-button and uses safari or google chrome**(in firefox on a desktop computer it works): Then the page-load-gif doesn't stop.
To get that fixed I used the following code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '[data-url="/anfahrt/"]', function (e) {
  $(window).on("pageshow", function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
    alert("From bf cache.");
    location.reload();
  }
 });
});
```

On my iphone the alert shows not until "wake up from standby". Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thank you!!

PS.: At the moment I use the following code so that the users doesn't get shown the loading image all the time but get hidden that at least after 5 seconds at the iframe-page:

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', '[data-url="/anfahrt/"]', function (e) {

    setTimeout(function() {
     $('#loading_image').fadeOut(1500);
    }, 5000);


 });
```

At the page http://m.alstaetter-tc.de/bilder/verschiedene everything works fine, so I think it has to do with the iframe...

Comment: Where are the events fired? Code is incomplete. Give us an example!

Comment: I don't know which code you are missing. I think only CSS is missing; what's not important in my opinion. If you want to see of course I can show you. What code do you miss? You can see live at http://m.alstaetter-tc.de/anfahrt.